# how to set direction of whole application to RTL?

Tags: android

I'm using API 17 and I'm looking for a way to set the whole app to rtl instead of using `<android:layoutDirection="rtl">` in every single activity layout.

Comment: You might try setting `android:supportsRtl=true` in your AndroidManifest.xml within the `<application>` tag.

Comment: @ PattaFeuFeu : that would only change the direction while the OS language is rtl.I wantto change the direction even when the OS is LTR

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I had the same problem , all you need to do is just consider all your used parent container (`LinearLayout` , `RelativeLayout` , `GridView` , etc) and set the LayoutDirection to RTL you can approach this way programmtically thanks to ViewCompat class to include api lower than 17.

`ViewCompat.setLayoutDirection(yourParentContainer,ViewCompat.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL)`;

**note that there is no need to set the Direction for childviews separately**

Answer (score 4):

Please check this text extract from android developers weblog:

> To take advantage of RTL layout mirroring, simply make the following
>   changes to your app:
>
> 1- Declare in your app manifest that your app supports RTL mirroring.
>   Specifically, add android:supportsRtl="true" to the 
>   element in your manifest file.
>
> 2- Change all of your app's "left/right" layout properties to new
>   "start/end" equivalents. If you are targeting your app to Android 4.2
>   (the app's targetSdkVersion or minSdkVersion is 17 or higher), then
>   you should use “start” and “end” instead of “left” and “right”. For
>   example, android:paddingLeft should become android:paddingStart.
>
> If you want your app to work with versions earlier than Android 4.2
>   (the app's targetSdkVersion or minSdkVersion is 16 or less), then you
>   should add “start” and end” in addition to “left” and “right”. For
>   example, you’d use both android:paddingLeft and android:paddingStart.

the full text can be found here:

http://android-developers.blogspot.ca/2013/03/native-rtl-support-in-android-42.html

Answer (score 4):

**The easiest and best way**
go to the `app/res/values/styles` and add below code to `<style>` tag, that you defined its name in android manifest
for example :

```
<style name"YourMainThemeName" parent="Parent Theme Of Your Choice">
    <item name="android:layoutDirection">rtl</item>
</style>
```

and now go to the `app/manifests/AndroidManifest.xml` and add below line code to `<application>` tag :

```
<application
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/YourMainThemeName">
</application>
```

now your layout directions is rtl.